# How to add corresponding Integer values in 2 different DataFrames

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have two DataFrames in my code with exact same dimensions, let's say 1,000,000 X 50. I need to add corresponding values in both dataframes. How to achieve that.

One option would be to add another column with ids, `union` both DataFrames and then use `reduceByKey`. But is there any other more elegent way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is good. Another option can be two take the RDD and zip those together and then iterate over those to sum the columns and create a new dataframe using any of the original dataframe schemas.
Assuming the data types for all the columns are integer, this code snippets should work. Please note that, this has been done in spark 2.1.0.

```
    import spark.implicits._

    val a: DataFrame = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
      (1, 2),
      (3, 6)
    )).toDF("column_1", "column_2")

    val b: DataFrame = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
      (3, 4),
      (1, 5)
    )).toDF("column_1", "column_2")

    // Merge rows
    val rows = a.rdd.zip(b.rdd).map{
      case (rowLeft, rowRight) => {
        val totalColumns = rowLeft.schema.fields.size
        val summedRow = for(i <- (0 until totalColumns)) yield rowLeft.getInt(i) + rowRight.getInt(i)
        Row.fromSeq(summedRow)
      }
    }

    // Create new data frame
    val ab: DataFrame = spark.createDataFrame(rows, a.schema) // use any of the schemas
    ab.show()
```

Update:
So, I tried to experiment with the performance of my solution vs yours. I tested with 100000 rows and each row has 50 columns. In case of your approach it has 51 columns, the extra one is for the ID column. In a single machine(no cluster), my solution seems to work a bit faster.

1. The union and group by approach takes about 5598 milliseconds.
2. Where as my solution takes about 5378 milliseconds.
   My assumption is the first solution takes a bit more time because of the union operation of the two dataframes.

Here are the methods which I created for testing the approaches.

```
  def option_1()(implicit spark: SparkSession): Unit = {
    import spark.implicits._
    val a: DataFrame = getDummyData(withId = true)
    val b: DataFrame = getDummyData(withId = true)
    val allData = a.union(b)

    val result = allData.groupBy($"id").agg(allData.columns.collect({ case col if col != "id" => (col, "sum") }).toMap)
    println(result.count())
    //    result.show()
  }


  def option_2()(implicit spark: SparkSession): Unit = {
    val a: DataFrame = getDummyData()
    val b: DataFrame = getDummyData()

    // Merge rows
    val rows = a.rdd.zip(b.rdd).map {
      case (rowLeft, rowRight) => {
        val totalColumns = rowLeft.schema.fields.size
        val summedRow = for (i <- (0 until totalColumns)) yield rowLeft.getInt(i) + rowRight.getInt(i)
        Row.fromSeq(summedRow)
      }
    }

    // Create new data frame
    val result: DataFrame = spark.createDataFrame(rows, a.schema) // use any of the schemas
    println(result.count())
    //    result.show()
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It seems like a plausible solution. Can you please comment on the performance difference with my proposition? I am sorry, I am a beginner in Scala and Spark.

Comment: Updated the answer, it seems the performance of union + group is a little bit slow. I can not say definitively though, hope it helps.

Comment: Hey, sorry for bothering again. The solution was working fine until a very small change. Now I have all the date as Double, and when I try to rowLeft.getDouble, it produces error "org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema cannot be cast to java.lang.Double". I can't see why it should not work, it is working absolutely fine when I get an Int, but not with Double.

Comment: It should work. Can you please share your code? Also the sample data you are using.

Comment: `val eventsRDD = machineDF.rdd.zip(diffMachineDF.rdd)
      .map {case (rowLeft, rowRight) =>
        val totalColumns = rowLeft.schema.fields.size
        val summedRow = for(i <- (0 until totalColumns)) yield rowLeft.getDouble(i) + rowRight.getDouble(i)
        Row.fromSeq(summedRow)
      }`

Comment: The data is something like (just one row): `[1.0,1.0,[-7.0E-4,-4.0E-4,100.0],[518.67,641.82,1589.7,1400.6,14.62,21.61,554.36,2388.06,9046.19,1.3,47.47,521.66,2388.02,8138.62,8.4195,0.03,392.0,2388.0,100.0,39.06,23.419]]`. This is the ourput of saveAsTextFile on the RDD.

Comment: Please ignore the square brackets. They were just formatted that way.

Comment: hmm, might be a data issue. I presume you are loading data from a csv file , right? Can you please give the output of these two command: `machineDF.printSchema(); diffMachineDF.printSchema();` I want to see the schema of the data loaded in the dataframes.

Comment: I must be doing something very very stupid. I did that again and it is working. And now Don't even know what was I doing wrong. Thank you very much.